# Best way to limit parallel request in a @RestController method

Tags: spring-boot, threadpool, spring-restcontroller

Considering the following code:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/requestLimit")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService service;

    @GetMapping("/max3")
    public String max3requests() {
        return service.call();
    }
}

@Service
public class TestService {

    public String call() {
        //some business logic here
        return response;
    }
}
```

What i want to accomplish is that if the method `call` from the `TestService` is being executed by 3 threads at the same time, the next execution generate a response with a `HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS` code.

Comment: You have to keep a Atomic variable and increment in your controller class. Increment it in your method and check if it exceeds 3 and if yes return else proceed

Comment: Thanks @pvpkiran, with your recomendation I managed to propose an answer

Comment: Use a `Semaphore` Which is designed for this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @pvpkiran comment I managed to code this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/requestLimit")
public class TestController {

    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Autowired
    private TestService service;

    @GetMapping("/max3")
    public String max3requests() {
        while(true) {
            int existingValue = counter.get();
            if(existingValue >= 3){
                throw new TestExceedRequestLimitException();
            }
            int newValue = existingValue + 1;
            if(counter.compareAndSet(existingValue, newValue)) {
                return service.call();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Service
public class TestService {

    public String call() {
        //some business logic here
        return response;
    }
}
```

With the corresponding exception definition:

```java
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS)
public class TestExceedRequestLimitException extends RuntimeException{ }
```